# exception determination how to know what to catch

Tags: android, media-player, try-catch

I do understand the basics of try and catch in as much as you try some code and look for errors that occur and catch them and then do something based on the error. I have code that when run looks for a complete video file exists on the SD card it plays the video if it is not complete it downloads it to the SD card then I want it to play.
here is my code block

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";    
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
public static final Context ACTION_VIEW = null;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
public String url = "";
public String fName = "";
public String vidName = "";
public String path="";
//final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     
    final String[] myAPP_FILES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.APP_FILES);
    final String[] myAPP_FILENAMES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.APP_FILENAMES);
    final String[] myAPP_NAMES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.APP_NAMES);
    final int[] myAPP_SIZES = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.APP_SIZES);

    setContentView(R.layout.video);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 

    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    url = myAPP_FILES[extras.getInt("key") ];
    fName = myAPP_FILENAMES[extras.getInt("key") ];
    vidName = myAPP_NAMES[extras.getInt("key") ];

    int fsize = (myAPP_SIZES[extras.getInt("key") ] -1 )*1000;

    File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fName );
    if (file1.exists()) {
        if(file1.length() < fsize) {
            file1.delete();
        }
    }


    loadMedia();

    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "" + file1.length()+ " " + fsize,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

        String pathfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +fName;

        try {

        Uri video = Uri.parse(pathfile);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
        } catch (Exception w) {}

}

private void loadMedia() {        

    //Check for media file download if not on sdcard
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fName );

    if (!file.exists()) {
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading to SD: "  + vidName + "\n...Please allow download to finish completely...");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

    try {

    URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
    conexion.connect();

    int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Length of file: " + lengthOfFile);

    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + fName);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
}

}
```

In operation a spinner is displayed and the user can select a video. It then checks to see if the file exists on the SD card if it is not it starts the download and a progress bar is displayed. Here is the problem At that time a message pops up that says:

```
    CANNOT PLAY VIDEO
    Sorry, this video cannot be played.
```

the download is progressing in the background and I can see the progress bar but it is darkened down
I do not want this message to appear.
I want to catch this and do nothing so the message will not appear

In the code I process the loadmedia function and then I set the video to play. I need to try and catch this step looking for this error message but I do not know what to look for 
in my logcat I see this

```
02-02 09:35:29.257: W/MediaPlayer(13311): info/warning (1, 26)
02-02 09:35:29.257: E/MediaPlayer(13311): error (1, -4)
02-02 09:35:29.277: I/MediaPlayer(13311): Info (1,26)
02-02 09:35:29.277: E/MediaPlayer(13311): Error (1,-4)
02-02 09:35:29.277: D/VideoView(13311): Error: 1,-4
```

I think it is included here but I don't know how to translate this into a valid try and catch routine
Hopefully someone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch an exception an exception must be thrown. Looks like you're already catching the base level `Exception` which would catch any *uncaught* exception from the media player layer. Therefore, they're not throwing any that they aren't catching themselves.

So this isn't about catching exceptions at this point but registering to receive notification of errors that the framework provides. Looking [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29) shows a way to register a listener for errors. Whether that means that the error won't show up as you've described is unknown. I suspect it'll still show. But you may have no control over that.